# Can't see HTTP POST parameters in firebug

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebug

I have `page,default.aspx`, with a button. On Click of it, I sent a "HTTP POST" request with query string parameters to some server which returned me jSON data and also redirected me back to  default.aspx

Now I wish to see what the request looked like and what all query string parameters was sent. 
However, in firebug(params) section, I can't see it. How do I view it ?

Comment: "returned me jSON and also redirected me back to default.aspx" - that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.... Could you clarify, possible show us some code?

Comment: Use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isnt it as simple as enabling Persist on the Net panel in Firebug and see the details of each entry?

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Persist

> When this option is enabled, the entries of the requests list are not
>   deleted when reloading the page. Instead the are grouped by page
>   request, which means, when reloading the page several times you will
>   get several request trees having the page title as root.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending query parameters, it's a GET request. You should not mix the POST and the GET method, or you will run into trouble.

Comment: There's no reason a POST request can't include querystring parameters. You just have to keep them straight.

Answer (score 0):

this code will log post or get data to your firebug window if found, place it in the page you request with ajax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameValueCollection n = Request.QueryString;
            int x = 0;
            Response.Write("<script>");
            foreach (string s in n)
            {
                // 3
                // Get first key and value
                string k = n.GetKey(x);
                string v = n.Get(x);
                // 4
                // Test different keys
                Response.Write("console.log('[" + k + "] => ");
                Response.Write(v + "');");
                x++;
            }
            if (x == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("console.log('QueryString is empty!')");
            }
            Response.Write("</script>");
        }
    }
}
```